# Can create hdfs file but cannot delete it

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I've created some files in my hadoop file system. Here is a listing of the files:

```
drwxr-xr-x   - hdfs hdfs          0 2016-08-16 15:49 /PSG/VideoVault
drwxr-xr-x   - hdfs hdfs          0 2017-02-16 16:39 /PSG/VideoVault/VideoStorage
drwxr-xr-x   - hdfs hdfs          0 2016-10-20 16:19 /PSG/VideoVault/VideoStorage/VICADS-0
drwxr-xr-x   - hdfs hdfs          0 2017-02-16 16:54 /PSG/VideoVault/VideoStorage/VICADS-0/155
drwxr-xr-x   - hdfs hdfs          0 2017-03-13 14:14 /PSG/VideoVault/VideoStorage/VICADS-1
drwxr-xr-x   - hdfs hdfs          0 2017-03-14 09:48 /PSG/VideoVault/VideoStorage/VICADS-1/101
-rw-r--r--   2 hdfs hdfs    1648728 2017-03-13 17:03 /PSG/VideoVault/VideoStorage/VICADS-1/101/20170313.idx
-rw-r--r--   2 hdfs hdfs 5765865482 2017-03-13 17:03 /PSG/VideoVault/VideoStorage/VICADS-1/101/20170313.img
-rw-r--r--   2 hdfs hdfs    1342200 2017-03-14 15:20 /PSG/VideoVault/VideoStorage/VICADS-1/101/20170314.idx
-rw-r--r--   2 hdfs hdfs 5060668142 2017-03-14 15:21 /PSG/VideoVault/VideoStorage/VICADS-1/101/20170314.img
```

However, when I go to delete the files, I get the error:

> Permission denied: user=wildfly, access=WRITE,
>   inode="/PSG/VideoVault/VideoStorage/VICADS-1/101/20170313.idx":hdfs:hdfs:drwxr-xr-x

I've set the `HADOOP_USER_NAME` system property to `hdfs` and the file is created with the correct user but somehow, when trying to delete, it is checking the user `wildfly` instead of `hdfs`. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

David

Comment: please post the command being used to delete the file

Comment: hdfsFileSystem.delete(indexPath, false);

where hdfsFileSystem is the org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem and the indexPath is the file to be deleted.